# How to provision Strapi data types via code?

Tags: strapi

I started to use Strapi and want to provision via code the data types.

Goal:
Create a set of predefined data types and collection types so everytime I start my project I can run this script/ts file to create the "Post" "Product" types automatically.

I am creating the Strapi project fine with

```
yarn create strapi-app strapi-blog-cms --quickstart --ts
```

and I see the sqlite db is stored at `.tmp/data.db`

I can technically store the `data.db` and copy paste next time I deploy but want a more cleaner and programmatical approach.

Something that

1. I can just clone/recreate the strapi project
2. run my "migrations/setup" to create the data types
3. Admins then fill the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest Strapi version 4.x this is done by the framework itself which exports the json schema once we create via ui a type `in development mode`.

Please keep that in mind, it works only in development mode!

There is a config-sync plugin that can export this file in the server as well.

So I would say as a solution the developer can set up the content types schema json then the content managers can just fill the data.

If they want changes in content type need to ask developers to do it.